# Handle "Error while copying content to a stream" Exception

Tags: c#, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

My C# app uploads file to some API, I'm using multipart request, i.e I'm uploading a json string and binary contect of the file, it works fine for most files, but for very few it gives exception, I mean let's try for file named `myFile128MB.dat`
I'm getting the exception:

> ::: Error while copying content to a stream. ::: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket had already been shut down in that direction with a previous shutdown call. ::: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Error while copying content to a stream. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket had already been shut down in that direction with a previous shutdown call. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket had already been shut down in that direction with a previous shutdown call
>      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginReceive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
>      at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.BeginRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.BeginRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
>      at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.StartReading()
>      at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartFrameHeader(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
>      at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartReading(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
>      at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
>      at System.Net.Security._SslStream.BeginRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
>      at System.Net.TlsStream.BeginRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState)
>      at System.Net.ConnectStream.BeginReadWithoutValidation(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
>      at System.Net.ConnectStream.BeginRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
>      at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.WebExceptionWrapperStream.BeginRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
>      at System.Net.Http.StreamToStreamCopy.StartRead()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>      at Lib.CheckPoint.ThreatPrevention.d__19.MoveNext() in D:\New folder\myApp.cs

My code looks roughly as follows:

```
public async Task<Dictionary<string , string>> Upload(string filePath)
{   
    var fi             = new FileInfo(FilePath);
    var jsonString     = "some json string";
    var fileContents   = File.ReadAllBytes(fi.FullName);
    var webService     = new Uri(url);
    var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post , webService);

    requestMessage.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
    requestMessage.Headers.Add("Authorization" , "MyKey1234");

    const string boundry = "------------------My-Boundary";
    var multiPartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent(boundry);
    var byteArrayContent = new ByteArrayContent(fileContents);
    multiPartContent.Add(byteArrayContent);

    var.Content = multiPartContent;
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();

    HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage , HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead , CancellationToken.None);
    //exception in this line ^
    return new Dictionary<string , string>();
}
```

The caller:

```
myDictionary = await Upload(filePath);
```

The structure of the console app is as follows:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args) => MainAsync().Wait();
    private static async Task MainAsync()  => new MyClass().Start();
}
```

And inside `MyClass:`

```
public async void Start() => myDictionary = await Upload(filePath);
```

Comment: That code wouldn't compile - you don't have a return statement anywhere in `Upload`. Please could you provide a [mcve] so we can try to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Okay, and does it fail with *just* the code you've presented? Again, it would be easier to help if we could reproduce the problem. Have you stepped through the code of `Upload` in a debugger? Where does it fail?